# Freezing on Logout / Disconnected SSH Connection

Tags: ssh, freeze, log, logout, openssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I have been having my Ubuntu desktop freeze occasionally when logging out of a graphical session (using computer locally), or when a remote ssh login (OpenSSH running on the desktop) is disconnected.

In the case of logging out, I see some white text on the screen listing what it is doing, and then it just stops.  I have to hold the power button to recover.

For SSH usage, the computer will lock up occasionally if my SSH session from my laptop ends irregularly.  For example, if I forget I am logged in and it auto-disconnects me, or if I lose internet connection, or if I sleep the laptop and the session times out.

Since both incidents involve a sort of

For the SSH freeze I have not been able to find any errors in the ssh server log or the system log.  The logs simply just end when the OS froze.

This problem has occurred on both 12.04 and 12.10 (both 64bit).

I am using a pre-configured HP Compaq 8200 Elite Small Form Factor.  It has an i7-2700K CPU with the Intel 3000HD integrated GPU and 12GB of ram.

I am unsure how to proceed in diagnosing/correcting this problem.

Thank you very much for your assistance!